# Check if I have an observer listening in firebase swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Before detaching a firebase handle or removing all observers, I want to check if there are observers listening in my app or I want to check if specific handle/observer is listening. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a firebase api to achieve this. I solved it using this workaround

```
var handle = ref.child("child").observe()

// check if nil before detaching listener
guard self.handle != nil else { return }
self.ref.removeObserver(withHandle: self.handle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,
If you are not setting multiple observers on the same reference, you can simply keep track of all your references with observers and just call `removeAllObservers()` on each of them. That way you don't have to keep track of handles and worry about checking for nil values.
For example,

```
var handle = ref.child("child").observe()
handle.removeAllObservers()
```